# Don't allow third-party javascript references to freeze site

Tags: javascript, external, freeze

**First some backstory:**

We have a website that includes a Google Map in the usual way:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=....></script>
```

Then there is some of our javascript code that initializes the map. Now suddenly yesterday pages started to load but then freezed up entirely. In Chrome this resulted in having to force quit and restart. Firefox was smarter and allowed the user to stop script execution.

Now after some debugging, I found out that a previous developer had included the experimental version of the Google Maps API:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp
```

So it's likely that something has changed on Google's servers (which is completely understandable). This has uncovered a bug on our end, and both in combination caused the script to hang and freeze up the website and the browser.

Now ok, bug is found and fixed, no big harm done.

**And now the actual question:**

Is it possible to somehow *sandbox* these external script references so that they cannot crash my main site. I am loading a decent amount of external javascript files (tracking, analytics, maps, social) from their own servers.

However such code could change at all times and could have bugs that freeze my site. How can I protect my site? Is there a way to maybe define maximum allowable execution time?

I'm open to all kinds of suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It actually doesn't matter where the scripts are coming from - whether an external source or your own server. Either way they are run in the clients browser. And that makes it quite difficult to achieve your desired sandbox behavior.

You can get a sandbox inside your DOM with the usage of iframes and the keyword "sandbox". This way the content of this iframe is independent from the DOM of your actual website and you can include scripts independent as well. But this is beneficial mainly for security. I am not sure how it would result regarding the overall stability when one script has a bug like an endless loop or similar. But imho this is worth a try.

For further explanation see: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/

Comment: I've indeed came across this trick for security purposes, didn't think of it to try it regarding freezes and endless loops.

Comment: I am not sure if this will help regarding those performance issues. But maybe someone can explain further.

Comment: I've just created a small-scale test using while(true) in an Iframe, and the page freezes just the same. The sandbox="allow-script" setting was set.